# Simple way to wait for a method to finish before starting another one

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I'm not familiar at all with Java threading :(. I have this class which, when called, constructs a new window (draw() method). The drawGUI() calls a processing method at the end (compare() method).

basically the structure is

```
public static void draw() {
    // draws stuff


    compare();
}
```

The problem is that the window drawn by drawGUI() has some major visual artifacts till the processing (compare() ) is over.

What is the simplest way I can implement to launch compare() after draw() has finished executing? Thank you

Comment: theoretically that is what should be happening. It does all of the code in //draw stuff then it does all of the code in compare(). Unless the code in //draw stuff creates a new thread.

Comment: it creates the window but it shows some visual artifacts, a black thick column and doesn't draw the components (buttons and textarea) until compare() is finished.

Comment: @ghostbust555 It might not be that simple as not having finished the draw method could be what's causing the visual artefacts (i.e., the calling method might have to do something else first).

Comment: I agree. But it is doing what it should be doing- finishing draw() before doing compare(). Which is not what the intended result should be I think

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Swing? Is that an Android app?

Comment: Swing. no, just a small java application in eclipse i need to build for a small project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to just put your `draw()` code inside an `asyncExec()` inside your thread at the end

> ```
> new Thread(new Runnable() {
> public void run() {
>
>     //do long running blocking bg stuff here
>     Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             draw();
>         }   
>     }
> }).start();
> ```

Comment: btw, a better way is using the Observer pattern... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: That's SWT specific (I think) - not sure if that is what the original question was about...

Comment: yeah you're right, it is, but there's a swing analogous call, SwingUtilities.invokeLater, but the heart of the question was threading timing issues, I didn't want to go google for the right swing call :-)

Comment: it doesn't recognize the class Display

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the reason you're getting the artefacts is that `draw()` hasn't had a chance to return, you can use a `Thread`.

```
final T parent = this;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        parent.compare();
    }
}).start();
```

(Where T is the type of the class that has your compare method).